# Swift 2 - for loop create multiple UIButtons

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton, swift2

I have a for loop that creates multiple buttons depending how may users are registered.

The buttons create fine, I have added a target to the button that needs to print which button has been pressed passing a value.

so far I have:

```
func loadUserVideos() {

        let userVideoNames = ["andrew", "john", "verya", "patry", "gabriy"]

        let countUserNames = userVideoNames.count - 1

        for index in 0...countUserNames {

            //print("\(index) times 5 is \(index * 5)")

            //UIBUTTON PLAY VIDEO USER
            let customButtonPlayVideoUser = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(145, 32, 64, 64))
            let imageCustomUserBtn = UIImage(named: "video-play.png") as UIImage?
            customButtonPlayVideoUser.setImage(imageCustomUserBtn, forState: .Normal)
            customButtonPlayVideoUser.addTarget(self, action: "CustomUserVideobtnTouched:", forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside)
            customViewUser.addSubview(customButtonPlayVideoUser)


        }

    }

    func CustomUserVideobtnTouched(sender: UIButton, index: Int){

        print(index)
    }
```

How can I pass the value to the action function so the app can see which button has been pressed?

Comment: You already have a reference to the button via `sender`, but you could also tag the button with `index` (`customButtonPlayVideoUser.tag = index`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use tag value:

```
       for index in 0...countUserNames {

            //print("\(index) times 5 is \(index * 5)")

            //UIBUTTON PLAY VIDEO USER
            let customButtonPlayVideoUser = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(145, 32, 64, 64))
            let imageCustomUserBtn = UIImage(named: "video-play.png") as UIImage?
            customButtonPlayVideoUser.setImage(imageCustomUserBtn, forState: .Normal)
            customButtonPlayVideoUser.addTarget(self, action: "CustomUserVideobtnTouched:", forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside)
            customViewUser.addSubview(customButtonPlayVideoUser) 

            /// set tag
            customButtonPlayVideoUser.tag = index
        }
```

and then

```
    func CustomUserVideobtnTouched(sender: UIButton){

        print(sender.tag)
    }
```

Comment: thank you so much. Is it possible to pass strings in the same way?

Comment: Can't. You have to create a subclass of UIButton if you want to store string.

Comment: Please solve this topic. Mark answer if my ans is correct. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

You can set the index to buttons tag properties and get the index like this in your selector methods,

```
sender.tag
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @PetroKorienev Passing the index of array to the buttons tag property will solve the problem. I've answered the same. Even author of question is also accepted the same answer as correct one. So, what is your problem?

Comment: The answer above has an example of how to achieve particular task, when yours one is a suggestion on a property to use. SO is the place extremely proud of quality content, and this is achieved by moderation - every post should be useful, informative and clear. Your post is rather a comment, not an answer. If you want to post on SO, consider making your answers a bit more wide. I'm not asking to write a poem, but 2-3 sentences and an example of usage will be quite enough for this particular question. SO already has 10 millions (imagine, 10 millions) posts and it's vital to make all them rock.

Comment: @PetroKorienev Since I don't have enough reputation to add comments, then How could I give solution / suggestion to anyone?

Comment: It's always difficult to start. The path of thousand miles begins from the first step. Consider adding a bit of content to the site (you need only 2 upvotes on answers or 4 upvotes on questions) to get comment privilege (Judging on your reputation, you already have one). If you want to answer - give a bit detailed, like i said above (or write a comment)

Comment: Thanks, I'll do as said.